# undefined character in monogodb script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following script that I run with the command load("test.js") in my mongodb shell.

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/CapabilitiesDB");
db2 = connect("localhost:27017/SAW");
db3 = connect("localhost:27017/dev");

var raw = db2.Requests.aggregate([
 {$match:{"AssignedToPerson":"Chase Wick"}},
 {
     $group: 
          {
           _id: "$AssignedToPerson",
           WorkingDuration : { $avg :  "$WorkingDuration" }
          }

     },
 {$project:{_id : 0, "WorkingDuration": 1}}
]);


db3.test.update(
   { "name" : "Chase Wick"  },

        { 
        $set:
      {
        "time" : raw.result[0].WorkingDuration
      }

     }
);
```

When I run this query in my RoboMongo or Mongo Shell command line it works perfectly however when I run this through my script it fails and say cannot load property 0 of undefined.  Essentially what this script is suppose to do is take the average time of someones work from one db and then insert it into a users table that holds their personal average time.

Comment: What is the contents of the `raw` variable after the call to the aggregation function? Looks to me like the error is being raised when trying to access `raw.result[0]` because `raw.result` is not defined.

Comment: My variable query gets this {
        "result" : [ 
            {
                "WorkingDuration" : 794.1458916675832100
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
    }               Using the raw.result[0].WorkingDuration for the $set function was the only way I was able to get my update query to update the average time in the users collection. If I didn't use that raw.result[0].WorkingDuration it would input the whole array instead of just the value.

Comment: You can use the [**`toArray()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) method to iterate the cursor and return the documents in an array, as in the following: `var raw = db2.Requests.aggregate(pipeline).toArray()` then update the `time` key with `raw[0].WorkingDuration`

Comment: var raw = db2.Requests.aggregate(pipeline).toArray([
 
 {$match: {
     $and: [
          {"AssignedToPerson":"Chase Wick"} ,
          {"WorkingDuration":{$ne:null}}
         ]
       }
    },
 
 
 {
     $group: 
          {
           _id: "$AssignedToPerson",
           WorkingDuration : { $avg :  "$WorkingDuration" }
          }
     
 }]
); I altered my query to what you suggested and it told me that pipeline was undefined